# jqgrid format column dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jqgrid

I am trying to format a jqgrid which has some dynamic columns which I create like this

```
  JQGridColumn column1 = new JQGridColumn() {
            DataField = "ID",
            PrimaryKey = true
        };
   ErrorsJQGrid.Columns.Add(column1);
```

How do I format these columns to have a say 'yellow background color'?  I can specify a  in the jqgrid columns definition, but since my columns are dynamically generated, I am not sure how it's done from the codebehind.

Here is the link to the demos [default formatter](http://www.trirand.net/examples/functionality/formatters/default.aspx), [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.net/examples/functionality/custom_formatter/default.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQGridColumn has the CssClass property which you can use to set custom CssClass for a column. Example:

In HTML

```
<style type="text/css">    
   .redColor { background-color: Red; }
</style>
```

In code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            JQGridColumn dynamicColumn = new JQGridColumn();
            dynamicColumn.DataField = "Freight";
            dynamicColumn.CssClass = "redColor";

            JQGrid1.Columns.Add(dynamicColumn);
        }
```

Will this work in your scenario?

Cheers,
Rumen Stankov
Trirand Inc (jqGrid makers)